# Creating a dependent drop down using laravel livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to use laravel livewire to create a dynamic dependent drop down list.
So I have created a livewire component named assignment.

assignment.blade.php

```
<div>
    <div class="row mb-4">
        <label for="category" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">Category</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select name="category" id="category" class="form-select col-md-6">
                <option value="null">Select category</option>
                @foreach ($categories as $item)
                    <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>     

                
    <div class="row pt-4">
        <button class="btn btn-warning text-white" wire:loading.attr="disable">Add New Product</button>
        <div wire:loading>
            Hold on...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

assignment.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Category;

class Assignment extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.assignment', [
            'Category' => Category::all()
        ]);
    }
}
```

The livewire component is embedded on the create.blade.php. Here is a snippet

```
 </div>

            <livewire:assignment />

            <div class="row mb-4">
                <label for="subcategory" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">Sub Category</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" class="form-select col-md-6">
                        <option value="null">Select subcategory</option>
                        <option value="wine">Wine</option>
                        <option value="whisky">Whisky</option>
```

Here is my productscontroller function that renders the view

```
public function create()
    {

        return view('products.create');
    }
```

routes

```
Route::get('/explore', [App\Http\Controllers\ConnectsController::class, 'index']);

Route::get('/p/create', [App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController::class, 'create']);

Route::post('/p', [App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController::class, 'store']);
```

I am getting the following error: syntax error, unexpected end of file.
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in assignment.blade.php.  @enforeach should be @endforeach.  I had to post this as answer as could not post this as comment.

Comment: Why couldn't you put it as a comment? Usually, typo-questions are off-topic for StackOverflow

Comment: Probably because I used @ sign in the comment.  Only realized this later.